# Convert a byte array to a fixed length alphanumeric string

Tags: java, hash

In Java, what's the best library/method to map a 13-character string to a 3-character string for the error check purpose? Thanks!

Comment: What's hcheck ? Is that a library you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method for this. You could implement a [24-bit CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), if you really mean 3 bytes rather than characters.

If you do mean `char`, what characters do you accept in the output? Only ASCII? Any Unicode character?

Comment: CRC is similar to what I want. Yes, ASCII is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to use the hashCode()

```
int threeByteHash = string.hashCode() & 0xFFFFFF;
```